# CSS pesudo-selectors parecem não funcionar com o método querySelector

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Basicamente, eu preciso acessar o **href** da última tag **anchor** e mudar o seu **valor**.

```js
const modHref = document.querySelector('.menu a:last-child');
modHref.setAttribute('href', 'ricardo.com');
console.log(modHref);
```

```html
<nav class="menu">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#animais">Animais</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dev →</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Mas, ao que parece, o método querySelector simplesmente ignora o pseudo-selector a seleciona direto a primeira **anchor**. Esse é um comportamento esperado ou eu estou ignorando alguma coisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc montou o seletor de forma errada.

Deveria ser `('.menu ul li:last-child a')` *pseudo-seletor na li*

Repare que vc não tem `<a>` irmão de `<a>` então todos são *first* e *last*. Para corrigir vc tem que selecionar a última `<li>` e ai sim o `<a>` dentro dela

```js
const modHref = document.querySelector('.menu ul li:last-child a');
modHref.setAttribute('href', 'ricardo.com');
console.log(modHref);
```

```html
<nav class="menu">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#animais">Animais</a></li>
    <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dev →</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```